# Stanza based auto-py-to-exe GUI app throws exception (Windows 10)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, stanford-nlp

I am building a Window based .exe for a python script using auto-py-to-exe. It uses Stanza. I am able to build and run the Console based version of the app (the GUI + Console). But the GUI only .exe (Console hidden) based on same auto-py-to-exe settings (except the GUI option) does not even load for the first time (double click run produces the following error):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stanza\models\common\utils.py", line 397, in get_tqdm
NameError: name 'get_ipython' is not defined

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "MFTE_gui.py", line 3, in <module>
        from MFTE import tag_MD, tag_MD_parallel, tag_stanford, tag_stanford_stanza, do_counts
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
      File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
      File "MFTE.py", line 16, in <module>
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
      File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
      File "stanza\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
      File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
      File "stanza\pipeline\core.py", line 23, in <module>
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
      File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
      File "stanza\pipeline\pos_processor.py", line 13, in <module>
      File "stanza\models\common\utils.py", line 405, in get_tqdm
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isatty'
```

Screenshot:
[image]

The relevant code from `stanza\models\common\utils.py` is as follows:

```
def get_tqdm():
    """
    Return a tqdm appropriate for the situation

    imports tqdm depending on if we're at a console, redir to a file, notebook, etc

    from @tcrimi at https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm/issues/506

    This replaces `import tqdm`, so for example, you do this:
      tqdm = utils.get_tqdm()
    then do this when you want a scroll bar or regular iterator depending on context:
      tqdm(list)

    If there is no tty, the returned tqdm will always be disabled
    unless disable=False is specifically set.
    """
    try:
        ipy_str = str(type(get_ipython()))
        if 'zmqshell' in ipy_str:
            from tqdm import tqdm_notebook as tqdm
            return tqdm
        if 'terminal' in ipy_str:
            from tqdm import tqdm
            return tqdm
    except:
        if sys.stderr.isatty():
            from tqdm import tqdm
            return tqdm

    from tqdm import tqdm
    def hidden_tqdm(*args, **kwargs):
        if "disable" in kwargs:
            return tqdm(*args, **kwargs)
        kwargs["disable"] = True
        return tqdm(*args, **kwargs)

    return hidden_tqdm
```

Edit2: I am using a Console widget to redirect terminal output to a text box ([link](https://www.reddit.com/r/Tkinter/comments/nmx0ir/how_to_show_terminal_output_in_gui/)). I disabled it to see if that was the issue. It was not. The GUI does not load after creating exe, whereas it does if I run the *.py file.

So what could be the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe it's trying to output something but has nowhere to do so. You could send all console output to a log file instead of printing it.

Alternatively, try experimenting with changing between tqdm and tqdm_notebook, depending on where you're running the code

Comment: I have updated the description above. This error happens at the very start: double click and run = this error window. I am waiting at this point for the window to load, which it does not.

Answer (score 0):

Add `from IPython import get_ipython` to `stanza\models\common\utils.py` until this is officially patched.